# getting user input using for loop and editbox

Tags: java, android, variables, for-loop, input

i have an array of string with different elements e.g name(?x) address(?y) and hasaddress(?x,?y). the signs of ?x and ?y serve as variables in these string. i have used the regex and patterns to get the ?x and ?y and remove the duplicates from the resulting array i.e ?x and ?y occured two two times each but my resulting array contains one ?x and one ?y as there values will be same.

next i can use the for loop in java to refer ?x and enter a value and ?y respectively. but i am confused in doing it in android as the editbox has to appear IF there is any variables available in the resulting array. in my scenario above in JAVA it asks two times for input value to ?x and ?y.

i need a logic for doing the same in android, what i have read so far is that if i use editbox in for loop it will take value for the last iteration only.

some said that there should be an array list that might contain the unique ids for every editbox and then iterate through the unique id array list and get value which seems too long procedure to do the small task of scanner in Java.

one other solution provided is to use the custom dialogue box which propmt user to enter value and i guess that will wait for the input before starting next iteration. Guessing becasue it is custom made and there is no direct input dialogue(please correct me if i am wrong)

to sum it up to: how to i take input in android from a user using a for loop and assign that input to different variable in every itertation.(this can lead me to solve my further problem by myself)

i will appreciate if any help or guidance is provided.

Note for editors: the values of ?x and ?y are as it is and as in my previous questions those were changed to x and y, this might cause confusion to other readers working on the horn clause expert systems.

Comment: this is too long to read and it gives me a headache. please tell us in short the problem, your actual solution (if you have), and the result you expect

Comment: Thanks you @Arctigor to sum it up to: how do i take input in android from a user using a for loop and assign that input to different variable in every itertation.(this is not exactlt the solution required but will lead me to next step)

Comment: I'd use the first solution you have written.

Comment: And as a suggestion, I'd use Set instead of List because sets removes the duplicates automatically, and you don't have to deal with it

Comment: That thing is already figured out, i just need some guidance on the input part. thanks for your valueable time @Arctigor

Answer (score 0):

Its better to get the variable values in one activity and process them all on the second activity instead of letting the code run the remaining portino of the code without stopping